# Open quote is expected for attribute "id" associated with an element type "OBJECT". file.html

Tags: eclipse, html, utf-8, xhtml

I have error in my html file, it was working but after some starting of server

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr" xml:lang="en"> 
<OBJECT id=idValue style="display:none;"></OBJECT>
</html>
```

I think I have error in encoding file

have you any idea about this error thanks

Comment: Is this real XHTML? (i.e. does it have a content-type of `application/xhtml+xml`)? If it is, you have many more errors than just the missing quote. OBJECT in capital letters, missing head and body elements, and a mismatch between the `lang` and `xml:lang` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using XHTML `id=idValue` is not valid - it must be `id="idValue"`. XHTML uses the XML rules which are much stricter than ordinary HTML.

Comment: But the question title contains "file.html", so I'm not entirely sure if this is really XHTML.